# Specific rewrite rule on htaccess with negation of word

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, regex-negation

I was trying to rewrite or redirect a URL with a regular expression based on the negation of a word.

The scenario is as following:

I have a wordpress installed on `example.com/wp-blog` but the visualization is through API on `example.com/blog`. I need to disable the access to `/wp-blog` and redirect it to `/blog` but preserving the access to `/wp-blog/wp-admin`.

I try the following condition on htaccess:

```
RewriteCond ^wp-blog/((?!wp-admin).)*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1  [R=301,L]
```

But with no success.

I also try this:

```
Redirect 301 ^wp-blog/((?!wp-admin).)*$ /blog/$1
```

And also this:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-blog/wp-admin $ /wp-blog/wp-admin $1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-blog/wp-login.php $ /wp-blog/wp-login.php $1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-blog/(?!.*wp-admin)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

I have no success with all combinations I try. So how can I redirect/rewrite `/wp-blog` to `/blog` but with access to `/wp-blog/wp-admin`?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `RewriteCond ^wp-blog/((?!wp-admin).)*$ [NC]` is an invalid Rewrite Condition. you missed the test string argument.

Comment: A RewriteCond doesn’t work that way, you have to specify a variable/value or something that you want to check to begin with. (Usually you want to check either REQUEST_URI or REQUEST_FILENAME in cases like this.) RewriteCond and RewriteRule work “as a team”, so you don’t have to cram all of this into the condition. Make the condition only check if what was requested did not start with `/wp-blog/wp-admin`, and then have the RewriteRule take care of matching the `wp-blog` part.

Comment: `Redirect 301 ^wp-blog/((?!wp-admin).)*$ /
blog/$1` is never going to work because of the unsupported Regex pattern.

Comment: So, according with your comments, I can't check with regexp + rewriteCond nor redirect. So I see something hard to achieve right now. Any ideas?

Comment: The best I think I can do is something like `RewriteRule ^wp-blog/((?!wp-admin).)*$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]`  but if this doesn't works I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: _“So, according with your comments, I can't check with regexp + rewriteCond nor redirect.”_ - no, that’s not what anyone said ...

Comment: Sorry for my bad english comprehension. Then you told me that I can check request_uri and redirect to /blog, but wp-admin I need to check an additional URI. That's possible?

Comment: I try several things with rewritecond with no success. Example: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(wp-blog)/((?!(wp\-admin|wp\-json|wp\-login)).)* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/wp-blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Example 2: `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^wp-blog/((?!(wp\-admin|wp\-json|wp\-login)).)*$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use request_uri to test if following path is wp-admin then write a rule to rewrite every thing to `/blog`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp-blog(?!/wp-admin)
RewriteRule ^/?wp-blog(/.*)? blog$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Fine, it works partially. It works on my root .htaccess file, but inside of `wp-blog` I have the wordpress htaccess file. If I delete the wordpress htaccess I can't access to REST API (on `/wp-blog/wp-json`), so I will play with the combinations and if I can't solve, I will ask you again. Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything with .htaccess, all you can be done with WordPress directly.

its can be done in two step

Step 1 : on your root create index.php with below content

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog/wp-blog-header.php' ); /** here wp-blog is place as your folder name */
```

Step 2 : now change "staging.domain.com" to "staging.domain.com/wp-blog" in your database ( for this download sql > open & edit for replace > upload new sql ).

**Now you full site run on staging.domain.com URL but files are call from "wp-blog" folder.**

Comment: If I do this I will get a wordpress on the staging.domain.com, but I develop the blog through REST API so is not valid for me. I need my site shown, but preserving access to `wp-blog/wp-admin`. Thank you for your answer